# UIButton SetImage property only displays image when clicked

Tags: xamarin.ios, mono, uibutton

I have a UIButton with an image set inside.
The image only shows up when the button is clicked, however I would like for it to be displays regardless of the button's status.

```
this.SetImage(image, UIControlState.Normal);
```

The image shows up when I have the mouse clicked down on the button.  I have tried other states--for instance, UIControlState.Highlighted, though the image would not display at all in this state.

Comment: Have you tried setting the image for multiple states? Something like : `SetImage(image, UIControlState.Normal | UIControlState.Selected | UIControlState.Highlighted);`

Comment: Yes, I have tried setting it for all sorts of combinations of states.

Comment: mmh and what about [SetBackgroundImage](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aMonoTouch.UIKit.UIButton.SetBackgroundImage(MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage%2cMonoTouch.UIKit.UIControlState))?

Comment: Are you sure something else isn't causing this? Your code above should work. Can you post more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIButton *m_btnSample = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [m_btnSample setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 300, 200, 40)];
    [m_btnSample setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley1.jpg"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self.view addSubview:m_btnSample];
```

acc to the above code wht i have written , the image is getting set regardless of the state